# Geocoding South African Addresses in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, geocoding, south-africa

I have about 8,000 addresses to geocode in South Africa. I haven't been able to find an address locator in ArcMap that works (trying to use the 'world places' address locator in ArcMap 10 gives me a "resource is not available, regardless of authorization" message.

In the past, I was using an online batch geocode tool from mapdevelopers, however this is limited to 100 records at a time.

Does anyone have info on an address locator for South Africa or another way of doing this?

Comment: I'm trying to get this into a shapefile: google.com/fusiontables/… I have exported to .kml and ran the convert KML to Layer tool in Arcmap, however I get an error message saying "error 000401: No features were found for processing".

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a good address locator but you could try Google's Geocoding service via Python:

```
import urllib
import json

GOOGLE = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'

def google_geocoder(query, from_sensor=False, googleGeocodeUrl=GOOGLE):
    """use google geocoder to get coordinates from adddress

    query -- address to geocode
    """
    query = query.encode('utf-8')
    params = {
        'address': query,
        'sensor': "true" if from_sensor else "false"
    }
    url = googleGeocodeUrl + urllib.urlencode(params)
    json_response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    response = json.loads(json_response.read())
    if response['results']:
        location = response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
        latitude, longitude = location['lat'], location['lng']
    else:
        latitude, longitude = None, None
        print query, "<no results>"
    return (longitude, latitude) # as x,y tuple

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # geocode Kruger National Park address
    x,y = google_geocoder('643 Leyds Street, Muckleneuk, Pretoria')
    print x, y
```

This returned:

`28.2043465 -25.7647932`

So if you had a long list of coordinates you could iterate through it and geocode them one at a time and create a Point feature class from the coordinates.  I do not know if there is a limit on how many requests can be made though.